# Prove that the rows of this matrix are proportional

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let
$n\geq3$ so that

$$ A := \begin{pmatrix}a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_n\\\ b_1 & b_2 & \dots & b_n\end{pmatrix} $$

Let matrix $B$ be the transpose of matrix $A$

$$ B := A^\mathsf{T} = \begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b_1\\\ a_2 & b_2 \\\ \vdots & \vdots \\\ a_n & b_n \end{pmatrix}$$

If the equation $\det(A \cdot B) = \det(B \cdot A)$, then prove that the rows of matrix $A$ are proportional.

Comment: What's $A\times B$?

Comment: It is the matrix A multiplied by matrix B , so i apologize for my lack of mathjax skills

Comment: @Serbacul It is more common to write $AB$ instead of $A \times B$. If any symbol is used to denote multiplication, this product might be written as $A \cdot B$ (`A \cdot B`). See [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), for instance.

Comment: @Serbacul Also, this statement is only correct if we are given that $n \geq 3$. If this information was a part of the question, then it should be included in your post.

Comment: thank you for your useful information , I have edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim, as was written (without $n\ge3$), was false because for $n=2$ the identity $\det(AA^\top)=(\det(A))^2=\det(A^\top A)$ holds regardless of what $\det A$ is, while your claim was that it's $0$.

Throughout, I'll call $a$ the first column of $B$ and $b$ the second column of $B$.

I assume that the hypothesis is that $n\ne2$. I'll also assume that the matrices are real, because for a reason that will become apparent later the claim is false in most other fields.

If $n=1$, then the rows are proportional and there is nothing to prove.

For $n>2$, $\det(A^\top A)=0$, therefore the claim reduces to $\det(AA^\top)=0$ implying that $\operatorname{rk}A<2$. Notice that $$\det (AA^\top)=\det\begin{pmatrix}a^\top a& a^\top b\\ a^\top b &b^\top b\end{pmatrix}=a^\top ab^\top b-(a^\top b)^2$$

This is the equality case of (real) Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, which occurs if and only if the two vectors are linearly dependent.

Sample cases, in fields that aren't subfields of $\Bbb R$, of $a^\top a b^\top b-(a^\top b)^2= 0$ despite $a$ and $b$ not being linearly dependent:

- if $n=3$ and the field is $\Bbb Q[i]$, $a=(i,1,0)^\top$, $b=(0,0,1)^\top$;
- if $n=5$ and the field is $\Bbb F_p$, consider four integers $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4$ such that $n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2+n_4^2=p$ and the vectors $a=(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,0)^\top$, $b=(0,0,0,0,1)^\top$

Comment: I understand everything until the last 2 lines , could you explain in more detail ?

Comment: @Serbacul A theorem of number theory known as *Lagrange's four-square theorem* asserts that all natural numbers can be written as the sum of four squares (possibly some of them being $0^2$). The purpose was making a counterexample, therefore you don't need the full result. You can just find special instances of this for $p=3$ or $p=5$.

Comment: Namely, for $n=5$ and the field being $\Bbb F_7$ you have $$\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}2&1&1&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\1&0\\ 1&0\\ 1&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}\right)=\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\1&0\\ 1&0\\ 1&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&1&1&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\right)$$